# Which is better: Rare or Epic?

Tags: smashy-road-wanted

In *Smashy Road: Wanted*, there are four rarities of cars: Common, Rare, Epic and Legendary.

On the prize machine they are listed in the order Common, Epic, Rare then Legendary.

However in the car selection screen they are arranged in the order Common, Rare, Epic then Legendary (with epic and rare swapped).

This makes me wonder: which rarity is better, rare or epic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The wikia](http://smashy-road.wikia.com/wiki/Cars) lists the cars: common, rare, epic, legendary.

[This german guide](http://www.corsual.com/smashy-road-wanted/tipps/guide-tricks-cheats-coins-werbung-autos-cars-freischalten_31814/) also lists them in that order.

> Kategorien Common (gewöhnlich), Rare (selten), Epic (episch) und Legendary (legendär)

Seems like it's just a little mistake from the developers at the prize machine.

Comment: Alternatively the devs just might be very bad at scrambling the rarities for the prize machine.